# Axios request to Flask app deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk not working

Tags: vue.js, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify

I have a Vue frontend deployed on AWS Amplify and a Flask backend deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

They are both successfully deployed. I can confirm that the backend is live by making an API call to my deployed backend using Insomnia. However, when it comes time to make the API call from the deployed frontend, the request doesn't work and I get a timeout after about 2 minutes.

Here's the code on the frontend that makes the call:

```
examDisplay.innerText = "Loading..."

try {
  const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/create`, {
    data,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  })
  const examData = response.data
  this.createExamHTML(examData, examDisplay)
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
  examDisplay.innerText = "Whoops, something happened!"
}
```

Here's the Flask app with the API endpoint that I'm trying to call

```
@application.route("/create", methods=["POST"])
def create_exam():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()["data"]
        is_dummy_exam = data["isDummyExam"]
        if is_dummy_exam:
            return dummy_exam
        
        topic = data["topic"]
        grade = data["grade"]
        num_questions = data["numQuestions"]
        num_choices = data["numChoices"]

        prompt = create_test_prompt(topic, grade, num_questions, num_choices)
        
        exam = generate_exam(prompt)
        return exam
    except:
        raise Exception("Something went wrong...")
```

I've changed the `BASE_URL` to the deployed backend's URL and it's as if the request gets lost. I checked the logs on Elastic Beanstalk and it's only capturing requests I sent from Insomnia and the exam component is stuck on 'Loading...'. I don't even get back the raise statement.

And it's not a CORS issue. My Flask app uses the flask-cors library.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Nvm solved the problem. The data was not being parsed as JSON so I passed the data into JSON.stringify()